# Number of Hausdorff topologies on a set with $100$ elements.

Tags: general-topology

> Find the number of Hausdorff topologies on a set with $100$ elements.

I know that number of topologies on a set with $2$ elements is $4$, with $3$ elements is $29$ , with $4$elements is $355$ , with $5$ elements is $7181$, ...etc.. But there are no general formula for a set with $n$ elements..

But I have no idea about the number of Hausdorff topologies...How we find it ? I saw this question in a competitive examination question and it was a multiple choice question. So I think there was a general formula to find the number...Otherwise a good and short approach to find it..

Please help...

Comment: Hmm. I'm pretty sure there's only one topology one a 1-element set. How many Hausdorff topologies are there on a 2-element set? or a 3-element set?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Every Hausdorff topology is $T_1$, which means that in a Hausdorff topology every finite set is closed. When the underlying set is finite, this means that *every* set is closed, and hence that every set is open. Thus, the only Hausdorff topology on a finite set is the discrete topology.

Comment: Sir I have a question...) According to your answer , number of $T_3$ topologies on a finite set is also $1$ and which is the discrete topology..Similarly , for $T_4$ and $T_5$ the argument is same..Is it ?

Comment: @S.Panja-1729: Yes, it is. You don’t start getting multiple topologies on a finite set until you go below $T_1$.

Comment: What happen for $T_0$ ?

Comment: @S.Panja-1729: In general more than one is possible, even if the points are unlabelled, but I don’t think that any general formula is known.

Comment: @S.Panja-1729: You’re welcome.